# Does "did" act like "indeed" in answers?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

From the anime, Naruto:

> Father: Hinata, I heard your mission was a failure.
>
> Hinita: Yes, it did fail.

That means it was indeed a failed mission. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, this looks like a use of the *emphatic do*: http://grammar.about.com/od/e/g/Emphatic-do.htm

Comment: It acts like indeed in that both are emphatics, but **indeed** is an adverb and **did** is a verb: one cannot directly replace the other. You can actually use both at once: "Yes, it did indeed fail".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of using the auxiliary verbs *did* and *do* in such sentences is just emphasising the main verb of the sentence.

Since, *indeed* is an adverb, as @JavaLatte pointed out in the comment, you can use both but if would be unnecessary since both *indeed* and *did* is there in order to do emphasise.